# How to fire an event on correct sequence of multiple key sequence?

Tags: qt, events

Hi I have successfully created an event based on a secret sequence of key. If user presses ctrl+alt+o i do an event.

Running code snippet

```
 act = new QAction(this);
 act->setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::ALT + Qt::Key_o));
 connect(act, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(slotclose()));
```

Now i wish to extend this secret key. I want the user to press two sequences. Ctrl+Alt+to  ctrl+alt+y. Only if these two sequences are fired in this order the event will be fired.

I doubt QKeySequences will work.

Comment: -1 There's even an example in the docs: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html#gnu-emacs-style-key-sequences.  Please do some research before posting, and please accept correct answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it can!!

All you need is to path it to a constructor:

```
act->setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::ALT + Qt::Key_O
                              , Qt::CTRL + Qt::ALT + Qt::Key_Y));
```